# Swift: textField listener not responding to text change

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

**FYI:** I am a JS developer, and recently started learning Swift. So I am not sure I am using the right terminology here.

In my app, I have a simple textField:
[image]
[image]
[image]

It is linked to this outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var activationCodeTextField1: UITextField!
```

The "listener" is implemented as follows:

```
self.activationCodeTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textField1DidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
self.activationCodeTextField1.delegate = self
```

`textField1DidChange` function:

```
 @IBAction func textField1DidChange(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("TextField1DidChange") 
       }
```

But, when I type something in the TextField, nothing gets printed.
So maybe `textField1DidChange` does not get triggered for some reason?

But, I really do not why.

Comment: I don't think `editingChanged` is the correct event for text changed. Try `valueChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Here is the sample code for you to test in playgrounds.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
        textField.placeholder = "enter text here"
        textField.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print(sender.text)
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ViewController())
```

The event `valueChanged` should be used to detect to see if the `text` has changed. `editingChanged` detects if the state of `UITextField` has changed between editing or idle states.

Replace:

```
self.activationCodeTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textField1DidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

With:

```
activationCodeTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textField1DidChange), for: .valueChanged)
```

Add-on: You don't need to put `self` unless you're inside a closure. And don't need the entire `UIControl.Event.valueChanged`, you can just put `.valueChanged` and it'll work fine.

Comment: Actually my original code works. The problem is that it was written in another function "setupView" and I forgot to call it inside viewDidLoad. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AhmedGhrib I tried out your code. It seems that it should have worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these delegates and target method just use action for editing changed.